# How can i design an application manager with GWT?

Tags: java, javascript, html, gwt

Considering the lack of reflection support on GWT, how can i design an strategy to build a web portal where i can aloud users to install new apps using my application manager API

any ideas?

SCENARIO:

Supose i develop an application manager for the client, with several apps defined.

Now i want to extend my appManager to develop an app to install apps.

I package a library with the API to comunicate with my manager, this would provide tools for any developer (or my self) to develop with this API and packague his APP, just like an OS

I've already do this with javascript, but it was very easy:

My app for installing save the package in the server file system and record the list of files on the database, and record also the apps name. Then i could show a menu with the options and hook his click event with the launch of the app that he represent by his name

You don't need reflection here because is a typeless languague. I just try no create an instance with the name (basically) and then call the methods on the objects. Those objects follow an interface.

with Java this can be achieved throught reflection. But in GWT i could not think in a similar solution

Comment: Why do need client-side reflection to do that? Maybe I just don't understand your question.

Comment: I am gonna explain it a litle more